# Show Message On Modal in Asp.net Core

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core-mvc

In My Project I Call (Edit,Delete,Detail) pages On Modal With Ajax .

```
  function Edit(id) {
     $.ajax({
         url: "/Customers/Edit/" + id,
         type: "Get",
         data: {}
     }).done(function (result) {
         $('#modal-info').modal('show');
         $('#modal-body').html(result);

     })
 }
```

When I have Error For Example this username is exists I Use to Show it With Validation Summary but My Problem Is When I Call Edit page When I Want Show Error I Must be use Return View() For returned Page and Show Error But Modal is Closed and and Go to page Edit

```
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (await _genericRepository.FindBy(f => f.FullName == customer.FullName) == true)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "This is Duplicate FullName");
                return View(customer);
            }
            else if (await _genericRepository.FindBy(f => f.Email == customer.Email) == true)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "This is Duplicate Email");
                return View(customer);
            }
            else
            {
                _genericRepository.Update(customer);
                await _genericRepository.SaveChangesAsync();
                return View("Index");
            }

        }
```

but I Want Show Message On Modal That Edit Page is in it.

How To Show Error Message When Call a Page in Modal with Ajax That  not Closed Modal and Show On it.